# Azure Blob Download Speed

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, vhd

I have a 137 GB blob .vhd file in my Azure Storage Container and am attempting to download it using the Azure portal.  Why is the download performance so horrible?  The browser is reporting >12 hours to download.  Why is is so slow?  Can anything be done to get it to download more quickly?

**UPDATE**
Here is the AzCopy usage. I am copying the VM image from one resource group to another.

```
$srcImageURL = "https://vmimagevhds.blob.core.windows.net/spservers/"
$srcImageKey = "mykey=="

$destImageURL = "https://vmsdisktorage.blob.core.windows.net/vm-images"
$destImageKey = "myOtherKey=="

$imageFileName = 'SP2016ServerUnconfigured-osDisk.86ca1057-af4c-4920-9082-6ad155ed2734.vhd'

# Concatenate and AzCopy command
# Paste into the Azure 
$azCopyCmd = "AzCopy /Source:" + $srcImageURL + " /Dest:" + $destImageURL + " /SourceKey:" + $srcImageKey + " /DestKey:" + $destImageKey + " /s /pattern:" + $imageFileName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to command line tool [AzCopy](http://aka.ms/azcopy) or its core library [Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement/), which supports super fast transferring for blobs and the transferring can be paused & resumed.

Comment: I have used AzCopy as well and realize it is suppose to have fast performance but I have not seen it yet.  The transfters between Resource Groups takes many, many minutes

Comment: Could you share details about how you're using it?